# Open file in a new instance of vim from nerdtree

Tags: linux, plugin-nerdtree

I'm actually using i3wmw so I'd like NERDtree, or any other option that works as a file tree to open the selected file in a new instance of vim, instead of in a new tab/buffer.

Is there anyway to make nerdtree work that way? If not, what other vim script or application would work like that? I'm using arch linux.

Thanks!

Comment: @DJMcMayhem the selected file

Comment: OK. And do you mean a new instance of vim, or a split window in the same vim?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem A new instance of vim

Comment: OK, thankyou. I edited some those details into your post if you don't mind. Also, [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21069769/3524982) looks like what you want. I would post some relevant details from it as an answer, but I don't know much about NERDtree, and I don't have it installed so I can't test it. It's a start though!

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069769/vim-nerdtree-open-in-new-window-instance-of-vim) looks similar. See if that works

Comment: @DurgaSwaroop that's not opening a new window, it's replacing the current

Comment: It works for `gvim` but not for terminal `vim`. To start a new vim instance in terminal, you have to start a new terminal. I might be wrong but I don't think Vim or NerdTree can do that.

Comment: @DurgaSwaroop If I can make the NerdTree execute the command _:xfce4-terminal -e 'vim $file'_ with $file being the selected file i NerdTree that would be great